# java.io.IOException: Cannot reset . What's wrong?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, exception, ioexception

I'm using com.nostra13.universalimageloader to load remote image into my app but in some images it shows this error:

```
11-10 14:27:39.631: E/ImageLoader(9207): Cannot reset
11-10 14:27:39.631: E/ImageLoader(9207): java.io.IOException: Cannot reset
11-10 14:27:39.631: E/ImageLoader(9207):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.MarkableInputStream.reset(MarkableInputStream.java:97)
11-10 14:27:39.631: E/ImageLoader(9207):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.decode(BaseImageDecoder.java:78)
11-10 14:27:39.631: E/ImageLoader(9207):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.downloadSizedImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:336)
11-10 14:27:39.631: E/ImageLoader(9207):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryCacheImageOnDisc(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:317)
11-10 14:27:39.631: E/ImageLoader(9207):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:258)
11-10 14:27:39.631: E/ImageLoader(9207):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:129)
11-10 14:27:39.631: E/ImageLoader(9207):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-10 14:27:39.631: E/ImageLoader(9207):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-10 14:27:39.631: E/ImageLoader(9207):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Does any one know what's is wrong?

That's my code in my adpter class:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_img_novo, null);

    TextView titulo_rs = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.titulo_cp_rs);
    TextView id_rs = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.pid);
    ImageView thumb_image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image_rs);

    HashMap<String, String> rs_listar_cp = new HashMap<String, String>();
    rs_listar_cp = data.get(position);

    titulo_rs.setText(rs_listar_cp.get(ListaCupons.TAG_TITULO_CP_RS));

    id_rs.setText(rs_listar_cp.get(ListaCupons.TAG_ID_RS));

    imageLoader.displayImage(
            rs_listar_cp.get(ListaCupons.TAG_LINK_IMAGE_RS), thumb_image,
            options);

    return vi;
}
```

Comment: Same problem here. Any answer???